# How to get whole index in ZEND Lucene?

Tags: zend-framework, symfony1, lucene, zend-search-lucene

Hi I am looking for a way to get the whole index if my query is nothing.

My lucene is a picture of my database without some unwanted content, like expired annonces... 
So I would like to use only lucene to get annonces, and for that I need a way to get the whole index.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer but something wich works for me: 
Using an indexKey like is_indexed, always true.

I am adding "is_indexed:1" to my query and it works...

If you have something else, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a field which is named after the index such as:

```
$oDoc->addField(
     Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword(
         'index',
         'availability'
     )
 );
```

Then the term query will return all fields. It's not pretty but it works fine.